# Problem with the subscripts of adjacent sums

Tags: subscripts

I have a problem with the subscript under the sum,

```
\sum_{i \in X} \sum_{i \in \bar{X}}
```

for example gives the subscript at different heights for each sum. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This can be solved using the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package and its command `\adjustlimits`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \adjustlimits\sum_{i \in X}\sum_{i \in \bar{X}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Vertical adjustments are also possible via `\vphantom`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \sum_{i \in X}\sum_{i \in \bar{X}} \quad \mbox{compared to} \quad
  \sum_{i \in X\vphantom{\bar{X}}}\sum_{i \in \bar{X}}
\]
\end{document}\end{document}​
```